# How to correct "Undefined variable: comment" error?

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

I keep receiving this error Undefined variable: comment and I am not sure how to fix it?

The controller:

```
class MessageController extends BaseController
public function display($comment)
{
    $message_id = $this->messageRepository->find($comment);
    return View::make('comments.show')->with('comment', $message_id);
}
```

The view:

```
<p>{{ $comment }}</p>
```

ErrorException
Undefined variable: comment (View: /views/comments/show.blade.php) 
(View: /views/comments/show.blade.php)
Open: /views/b3d5c72416fd9f623fa2cea68be0164f

Comment: And where do you get that error exactly?

Comment: On the view that is why I included it.

Comment: Are you sure? This piece of code rather wouldn't throw that error, so check the stack trace.

Comment: I have check twice it keeps coming back to that view.  Its why I asked for help because I can not figure it out.

Comment: So show the stack trace

Comment: In the stack trace you have exact line, where the error occured. This is what you are looking for.

Comment: Its line 1 I didn't include it because I didn't think it made a difference because there is only one line of code.

Comment: So maybe you have a typo in the `with`? There is no way that error is thrown with that setup. Even if it's `null` it still will be defined.

Comment: What do you mean in the 'with'?